# Undefined method '*' for nil:Nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an application that is like a forum.  It displays all data in a table.  So what I am trying to do is sort the dates in the table in ascending order.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
def pullTenRecords

if session[:page] == 0

     tenRecords = Consciousmess.limit(10).offset(0)
     orderedTenRecords = tenRecords.order(created_at: :asc)


   else 
      tenRecord = Consciousmess.limit(10).offset(session[:page] * 10)

      orderTenRecords = tenRecord.order(created_at: :asc)
        end
    end
```

My problem is it says undefined undefined method '*' for Nil:NilClass.  I do realize there are some posts about this on StackOverflow but none of the posts have really helped in terms of solving my issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `session[:page]` is `nil`. Just set default value if it `nil`:

```
def pullTenRecords
   session[:page] ||= 0
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  What I did is inside the else loop I set session[:page] = session[:page].  That fixed the issue.  Thanks again